# How to convert html to pdf in a node and aws-lambda environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, puppeteer, html-to-pdf

My goal is to build a node with an express app that receives a JSON, converts to HTML, and finally to a PDF.
The app must be deployed on AWS Lambda which has **250 MB** maximum deployment package size (unzipped).

I have the JSON to HTML sorted; however, the HTML to PDF conversion remains a challenge. I noticed the most popular solutions involve puppeteer, which uses a headless-chrome-crawler containing an install size of [227 MB](https://packagephobia.com/result?p=headless-chrome-crawler). That is a no-go given the AWS Lambda requirement.

Other solutions I found mention the use of deprecated technology such as phantomjs. I prefer to avoid those for safety's sake.

Are there any seamless, lightweight solutions to convert HTML to pdf on a node/lambda environment?

Comment: You can make use of NodeJS layer in AWS Lambda. https://explainexample.com/computers/aws/aws-lambda-layers-node-app

Comment: From the docs: 
"...total unzipped size of the function and all layers should not exceed the unzipped deployment package size limit of 250 MB."

Answer (score 1):

I ended up following this [article](https://medium.com/@keshavkumaresan/generating-pdf-documents-within-aws-lambda-with-nodejs-and-puppeteer-46ac7ca299bf) and things worked fine. I could deploy puppeteer-core inside the lambda and the total package size was under the 250MB limit. No need for lambda layers.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda layers are what you are looking for, you can just setup a docker container containing all the required dependencies for your lambda to run on top of.